# Resolving POP UP Window Resizing issues

Tags: javascript, css

HI ,

I have a div , which represent a Chart as shown below

```
<div  class="centered" id= "finance"/>


.centered {
left:33px;
 margin: 0 15%;
}
```

This page is opend as a POPUP WIndow . 
When the  popup window is resized , i want my chart to b aligned correctly .

Please tell me how to achive that

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `left:33px`

Add `margin:0 auto;` (as @uncollected mentioned)

Set a `width`, example `width: 600px`

`margin:0 auto;` will center an item, but it needs an explicit width.